# Swashbuckle - {lang}/api_controller/parameters

Tags: swagger-2.0, swashbuckle

I am trying to implement Swashbuckle with an existing .net API.
The current design of the API is that each call has a prefix of the localization 
i.e. 
`GET {lang}/API_Controller/API_Function/{format}/{parameters}?{more parameters}`

(yes - I think the design could have been different...).

When trying to run http:\localhost/swagger I get a null value for the {lang} value in the CultureHandler.cs .

Since I cannot change the API I need to set the Swashbuckle (or swagger) to have some sort of route handling (to manage the {lang} prefix).

Should I try to work with the SwaggerConfig.cs using the c.RootUrl config or maybe try to alter the RouteConfig.cs

Any ideas would be appreciated.